# Should the user input be escaped in dynamic SOQL when using binding?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

Given the following query:

```
public List<Account> selectById(Set<String> names)
{
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :names ORDER BY Name';
    List<Account> records = Database.query(query);
    return records;
}
```

Should the `names` collection be sanitized in the following query before it gets to the query?

```
for (String name : names) 
{
    name = String.escapeSingleQuotes(name);
}
```

Comment: You can do binding in the string itself and use `Database.query()` to execute it?! You just made my day!!

Comment: Be aware you can't bind to anything like a function call result or object property/field value without the use of a local variable initialized from the value in a dynamic query string, unlike a static query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no. Because you are using a binding there is no possibility for the value to introduce an SOQL injection attack. It is only when you are textually inserting the value into a generated query that you need to do the escaping.

Comment: Why is this the "short answer"?  There could be other vulnerabilities?

Comment: @BrianMiller, nah, just that it is a literally short answer. "No." I then added a bit of detail :)